# Tight Asymptotic for Sum Involving Primes

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Can we find a tight approximation or a good lower bound for the following sum: $$\sum_{\text{prime } p \le n} \log_p(n)^{1/2} \ ?$$

So far, I can only come up with a very untight bound of $\ge \pi(n).$ I think the sum is at least $C \pi(n)$ for a constant $C$. I am hoping that this sum is at least $f(n) \pi (n)$ for $f$ that goes to $\infty$ with $n$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Write it $$\sqrt{\log n}\sum_{p \leqslant n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log p}}$$ and apply summation by parts.

Comment: A bound that is slightly tigher  than your bound is:

$$N_\text{primes} \log_{p_\text{max}}(n)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Obviously $\limsup_n \frac{\sum_{p \le n} \sqrt{\log_p(n)}}{\pi(n)} \le 1$. Just note for any $\epsilon > 0$, $$\sum_{p \le n} \sqrt{\log_p(n)} \le \sum_{p \le n^{1-\epsilon}} \sqrt{\log n} + \sum_{n^{1-\epsilon} \le p \le n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon}} \le \sqrt{\log n}\cdot \pi(n^{1-\epsilon}) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon}}\pi(n)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abel's sum formula yields

\begin{align}
\sum_{p \leqslant n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log p}}
&= \frac{\pi(n)}{\sqrt{\log n}} + \frac{1}{2} \int_2^n \frac{\pi(t)}{t(\log t)^{3/2}}\,dt \\
&= \frac{\pi(n)}{\sqrt{\log n}} + \frac{1}{2}\int_2^n \frac{1}{(\log t)^{5/2}} + O\biggl(\frac{1}{(\log t)^{7/2}}\biggr)\,dt \\
&= \frac{\pi(n)}{\sqrt{\log n}} + \frac{n}{2(\log n)^{5/2}} + O\biggl(\frac{n}{(\log n)^{7/2}}\biggr)\,.
\end{align}

Thus

$$\sum_{p \leqslant n} \sqrt{\log_p n} = \pi(n) + \frac{n}{2(\log n)^2} + O\biggl(\frac{n}{(\log n)^3}\biggr)\,.$$

So $\pi(n)$ is not a very crude estimate, it is asymptotically equal to the sum. It underestimates the sum, and we can say by how much (within the bounds we know for $\pi(x)$), but the main term is $\pi(n)$.